# Python - pass a list as params to SQL, plus more variables

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pypyodbc

I'm trying to pass a an unknown number of params to SQL Server in python 3.6.  Here is my code using pypyodbc:

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
theargs= ['1033286869','1053474957','1063654630','1104116235','1104910306','JASON']

thesql = """SELECT * 
            FROM BI_DUPLICATES_STAGE_0 
            WHERE DUP_ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            AND FRST_NM = ?
         """
cursor.execute(thesql, theargs)
resultset = cursor.fetchall()
```

This works.  However, I'm never sure how many DUP_IDs I'm going to have.  I've seen some examples of using a list, but then if I have another variable such as is this case, `FRST_NM`, then I can't just use the list.

So if somebody could provide a simple example of having a list (of varying length), and another variable and how to get SQL to run that I would greatly appreciate it!  I'm not bound to using pypyodbc if that is the issue and there is another way to do this.

UPDATE:
Thank you for the nicely formatted answer.  Just one quick follow-up question.  I'm still a little unclear how I would format 2 lists if I had to produce something like:

`SELECT * FROM BI_DUPLICATES_STAGE_0
WHERE DUP_ID IN (1033286869, 1053474957, 1063654630, 1104116235, 1104910306)
AND MID_NM IN ('SMITH','JON')
AND FRST_NM = 'JASON'`

Without the nice format join, I have some mess like this:

`SELECT * FROM BI_DUPLICATES_STAGE_0 
WHERE DUP_ID IN (?,?,?,?,?)
AND MID_NM IN (?,?)
AND FRST_NM = ?`

How would I format the list twice as suggested?  Keeping in mind I won't know how long each list (the ID and MID_NM) are actually going to be.

Comment: *I have some mess like this*...why is that query a mess? That is a prepared statement for a parameterized query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider formatting the string to dynamically build `?` placeholders by length of lists, *theargs* and *otherargs*. Do note the last name should be at end of param list to correspond to last `?` placedholder. Once done building the prepared statement, pass to `cursor.execute()` with param values:

```
theargs= ['1033286869','1053474957','1063654630','1104116235','1104910306']
otherargs = ['SMITH','JON']
lastarg = ['JASON']
allargs = theargs + otherargs + lastarg

thesql = """SELECT * 
            FROM BI_DUPLICATES_STAGE_0 
            WHERE DUP_ID IN ({})
            AND MID_NM IN ({})
            AND FRST_NM = ?
         """.format(",".join(['?' for i in range(len(theargs))]),
                    ",".join(['?' for i in range(len(otherargs))]))    
print(thesql)

# SELECT * 
#             FROM BI_DUPLICATES_STAGE_0 
#             WHERE DUP_ID IN (?,?,?,?,?)
#             AND MID_NM IN (?,?)
#             AND FRST_NM = ?

cursor.execute(thesql, allargs)
```

Comment: Interesting!  If my WHERE clause was something like: WHERE id IN (1,2,3) AND othervalue IN ('a','b','c') AND name = 'Bob' would there be a clever way to handle multiple lists of unknown lengths that I'm not seeing?  I'm just surprised there isn't a simple IN (@list) kind of parameter way to pass stuff :)

Comment: You would need to format twice for both lists. SQL is declarative language. So as soon as a table, column, variable, even clauses like `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` or `JOIN` is declared it is immutable. Hence, it cannot dynamically change per conditions. Python can dynamically build the string but once built, SQL processes in one call.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  I've updated the question with a small follow-up.  I'm a little unclear how I would format twice for both lists :)

Comment: See update. Simply extend [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with another `.join` string. Also note how the `FRST_NM` param should be placed at the end. By the way, hopefully your lists do not extend to thousands as various databases have limits of values in `IN()` clause. Consider using temp tables for such large lists.